# Osclass plugin add unneeded table on searching

Tags: osclass

I use [cars plugin](http://market.osclass.org/plugins/cars-attributes_7) and I replicated the plugin to add another plugin, motorbike. the two plugins work very well but there is a fatal error on searching. Somehow they add another unneeded table on searching (I see the tables when debugging the plugins). for example, when I search on the car category, the query add the motorbike table. I just add the car table not the motorbike's one. otherwise when I search on the motorbike category, the query add the car table. It makes me confuse. the result never correct. Is this a bug? I'm using Osclass 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. may be my solution is not clean but it works for me. I have to edit Search.php file in /oc-includes/osclass/model/ directory. I replicated two functions, addTable and addConditions. but I added a new parameter, the category ID.  so it'll be : addTableNew($tables,$catID) and addConditionsNew($conditions,$catID)

```
public function addTableNew($tables,$catID)
    {
        if(is_array($tables)) {
            foreach($tables as $table) {
                $table = trim($table);
                if($table!='' && in_array($catID, $this->categories)) {
                    $this->tables[] = $table;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $tables = trim($tables);
            if($tables!='' && in_array($catID, $this->categories)) {
                $this->tables[] = $tables;
            }
        }
    }

public function addConditionsNew($conditions,$catID)
    {
        if(is_array($conditions)) {
            foreach($conditions as $condition) {
                $condition = trim($condition);
                if($condition!='') {
                    if(in_array($catID, $this->categories)) {
                        $this->conditions[] = $condition;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $conditions = trim($conditions);
            if($conditions!='') {
                if(in_array($catID, $this->categories)) {
                    $this->conditions[] = $conditions;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then in index.php file on the each plugin directory. I changed cars_search_conditions function and motorbikes_search_conditions function.

```
function cars_search_conditions($params) {
// we need conditions and search tables (only if we're using our custom tables)
$cats = ModelCars::newInstance()->getCategoryId('Cars');    //-->search the category id in the database
$catID = $cats['fk_i_category_id'];
$has_conditions = false ;
foreach($params as $key => $value) {
    // we may want to have param-specific searches
    switch($key) {
        case 'make':
            if( is_numeric($value) ) {
                Search::newInstance()->addConditionsNew(sprintf("%st_item_car_attr.fk_i_make_id = %d", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $value),$catID);
                $has_conditions = true;
            }
        break;
        //others search param
    }
}

// Only if we have some values at the params we add our table and link with the ID of the item.
if($has_conditions) {
    Search::newInstance()->addConditionsNew(sprintf("%st_item.pk_i_id = %st_item_car_attr.fk_i_item_id ", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, DB_TABLE_PREFIX),$catID);
    Search::newInstance()->addTableNew(sprintf("%st_item_car_attr", DB_TABLE_PREFIX),$catID);
}
```

}

```
function motorbikes_search_conditions($params) {
// we need conditions and search tables (only if we're using our custom tables)fk_i_category_id
$cats = ModelMotorBikes::newInstance()->getCategoryId('Motorbikes');
$catID = $cats['fk_i_category_id'];
$has_conditions = false ;
foreach($params as $key => $value) {
    // we may want to have param-specific searches
    switch($key) {
        case 'make':
            if( is_numeric($value) ) {
                Search::newInstance()->addConditionsNew(sprintf("%st_item_motorbike_attr.fk_i_motorbike_make_id = %d", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $value),$catID);
                $has_conditions = true;
            }
        break;
        //others search param
    }
}

// Only if we have some values at the params we add our table and link with the ID of the item.
if($has_conditions) {
    Search::newInstance()->addConditionsNew(sprintf("%st_item.pk_i_id = %st_item_motorbike_attr.fk_i_motorbike_item_id ", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, DB_TABLE_PREFIX),$catID);
    Search::newInstance()->addTableNew(sprintf("%st_item_motorbike_attr", DB_TABLE_PREFIX),$catID);

}
```

}